# ZooKeeper interface for PHP

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I already have a ZooKeeper cluster up and running, but I want to interface with it through PHP code? I've seen the ZooKeeper php extension on GitHub (https://github.com/andreiz/php-zookeeper) but I'm new to PHP/ZK and I'm not sure how to get started with connecting to ZK using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the same PHP client and did not have any problem. It is a pretty good API. I followed the steps from here to get started:
http://systemsarchitect.net/distributed-application-in-php-with-apache-zookeeper/

And then you can also view the example code on GitHub.